# He's laying it down?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

What's the meaning of:

> He is laying it down!

I'm watching [a MSNBC commentary about Syria war and @3:38](https://youtu.be/_O2TRzA2ezk?t=200), which the host is astonished by a truth being told by a guest and said this sentence, so what's the meaning of it?

**Note**: The video contains opinions about the conflict in Syria. I am only interested in the English. Please do not click the link if you don't want to hear about the topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Laying it down" is an informal idiom meaning "making a candid statement." The subtext is that someone making such a statement is putting out the most honest statement he can make.

In the context of the video, the announcer is conflating "making a candid statement" with "making a truthful statement"—although that does not necessarily follow. Certainly someone who is "laying it down" normally *believes* he is making a truthful statement, but truth and candor are not necessarily the same thing.

Sometimes "laying it down" will be expressed as "laying it down for all to see," which is another expression of candor.